# regular expression match and replace or match and split

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble reusing the matched part of a regular expression. The issue isn't finding with the regular expression, but using it to replace or split a string using the matched part.

Below the before and after I'm looking fore.

before:

```
AB_C_DE01FGHI0123456789_XXX_202201.pdf
```

after:

```
AB_C_DE01FGHI0123456789_XXX_2022-01.pdf
```

The only difference is that it splits the 6 digits in a group of 4 and 2 and concatenates it with a dash '-'

```
202201 to 2022-01
```

Here is the regex string I'm using to match the 6 digits and '.pdf'.

```
\d{6}(?:.pdf)
```

Which will match:

```
202201.pdf
```

And now for the difficult part, I want to reuse the match part and replace/split it so that the new string looks like this:

```
AB_C_DE01FGHI0123456789_XXX_2022-01.pdf
```

So my questions boils down to how to use regular expressions in the replace part.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I just noticed a design flaw in my thinking, I could off-course match multiple groups and than adding them together again. 
Regex search string: "(\d{4})(\d{2}(?:.pdf))"
And than combining it with: "$1-$2"

Comment: Yup that would be the simple solution...

Comment: Hi Nick, I'm using python. But it was an open question on regular expression usage.

Comment: Understood, but some languages have optimisations that can make certain tasks simpler, so it's always helpful to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search using this regex with 2 capture groups:

```bash
(_\d{4})(\d{2}\.pdf$)
```

Replace it with:

```bash
$1-$2
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BxOI4i/1)

**Breakup:**

- `(_\d{4})`: Capture group #1 to match `_` followed by 4 digits
- `(\d{2}\.pdf$)`: Capture group #2 to match 2 digits followed by `.pdf` before end